# Why can't i push my files on github. It shows that i don't have the correct access rights or the repo doesn't exist. How can i resolve this?

Tags: github, push

I am trying to set up my local computer to be able to send files up on github but for some reason i am facing several issues while doing so.[image]

So this is what  it shows on cmd.
[image]
And this is what it shows on github page.
As you can notice it shows i made the last change a week so obviously my commits weren't pushed to the main branch.
Please help me figure out what the problem is here.
The name of my repo on github is MyWebsite and the local folder is mywebsite. Perhaps that is causing the issue? I also have generated a ssh key if that's a matter of concern.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you set your generated ssh key in your settings of github account ?

Comment: I don't remember doing anything like that as I did it out of curiosity and didn't know much about it at the time. Is it that important? How can i do that? I can generate a new ssh key.

Comment: Try following these steps https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Answer (score 1):

I will go through step by step what you need to do:

1.**Checking for existing SSH keys**

Before you generate an SSH key, you should check if you already have an existing SSH key. You can easily check for existing SSH keys by using the **Git bash** and entering the following command that lists the files in the `.ssh` directory which has been located most often on following path `C:\Users\Jakobson\.ssh`. For this example I used my path from my local.

Command for checking the files where ssh keys have been stored after generating is:

`ls -al ~/.ssh`

By default, the filenames of the public keys are one of the following:

`id_rsa.pub id_ecdsa.pub id_ed25519.pub` .

If `.ssh` directory haven't any existing files, you should generate new ssh key which is described in next step.

2.**Set up an SSH key**

You can generate an SSH key by running the `ssh-keygen` procedure on your computer. You will need to remember where you have saved the generated public and private RSA key pair. The steps for generating a new SSH key are:

- Open the Git bash.
- Enter the following command by entering your GitHub email address:

`ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "youremailaddress"`

Note:  If you are using a legacy system that doesn’t support the Ed25519 algorithm, use:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "youremailaddress"`

This creates a new SSH key using the provided email as a label.

- Next thing git bash will ask you to enter the file destination where ssh keys will be generated like this:

`> Enter a file in which to save the key (/c/Users/Jakobson/.ssh/id_ed25519):[Press enter]`

If you press enter, it will be saved automatically in `.ssh` directory, or you can specify other destination path.

- Then you will be asked to enter a passphrase. You can leave it empty.

`> Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Type a passphrase]`

`> Enter same passphrase again: [Type passphrase again]`

After this, ssh keys will be generated in your `.ssh` directory.

3.**Adding Your SSH Key to the ssh-agent**

You can start the ssh-agent in the background by typing in your git-bash:

`` eval `ssh-agent -s ``

And then you can add the private key file that you have generated by typing:

`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

4.**Adding the SSH Key to Your GitHub**

You need to copy SSH public key to your GitHub.

- Copy all content from `C:\Users\Your machine name\.ssh\id_rsa.pub` file
- Go to `https://github.com/settings/keys` -> SSH and GPG keys and click on new ssh key. Name ssh key optionally, and paste content from your file. That is all.

If you want to add ssh key to specific repository on remote server, go to your repository settings, then go to deploy keys and add ssh key on the same way we did before. You can see that at this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4OQf.png

Note: If you need to type your password when you try to push on server again, type your fingerprint which has been generated after adding ssh key on your profile/settings/keys and value is something like: `SHA256:rLiDkFpEz9FT3/9cNVu9NlL8BIxCS` you will find that in your ssh keys of your profile.

Comment: Hey thanks for the detailed reply. I have a few questions regarding this entire procedure. I have already generated a ssh key from the github page. Will that be an issue? also how can i copy contents from the .pub file? It asks for some kind of software that supports this format when i try to open the file. Also will this ensure I don't have to enter my username and password everytime i try to push content on my github repo?

Comment: You welcome. If you already generated your ssh key on github page, you actually have ssh key. That won't be an issue. You just need to enter your fingerprint then instead of password when you are trying to push to remote server from git cmd prompt and after that you dont need to enter everytime when you trying to push some changes on specific repo. For myself, I am copying entire content of id_rsa.pub file from Notepad++ editor, but you can open from ordinary notepad.

Comment: Thanks but everytime i try to push on git bash it shows the above prompt and says the access is denied. What can i do? It doesn't even ask for the username and password and simply shows the prompt you can see above.

Comment: Try run this command into git bash **ssh -T git@github.com**. If problem still exists, you probably have problem with ssh-agent, and then you can try again on step 3 in my answer. You can use also different approaches to solve your issue, if it is not necessary to work with ssh. You can clone again your repo to work with https instead of ssh by following screenshot https://i.imgur.com/p5OV2H2.png.

Comment: it still shows permission denied(publickey).

Comment: I wanna get to the root of this issue here. What do you think is causing the issue?

Comment: I am not sure anymore, you can check this out https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey or you can search  here, here are many questions same as yours

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new token at: https://github.com/settings/tokens

- Generate a `new token` (classic); and
- then try to git clone a repo.

After inserting the login name you will be asked to enter the password. Use the generated token as the password.